# Android: Limit supported devices in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I have an application in the market that I want only Nexus S-users to be able to download.
How can I do this?

There is a "Supported Devices" in the publishing process, but I dont want to exclude devices 700times.

Can I in the manifest support only the Nexus S?

Dag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to exclude all other devices instead of the filtering by features of the device, but I'd suggest following the directions for [Market Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) in the Android Developer Documentation that is provided by Google.  I'd suggest using the Nexus S specs as the minimum specs and go from there.

EDIT:  Google recently released a [Device Availability Dialog in the Developer Console](https://market.android.com/support/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1286017) that allows you to understand which devices can run your application, as well as allowing you to filter out devices that you don't want to run your application.

Comment: It is a buissniss application, and all the clients are bought by me, and they are nexus S devices.

Comment: There is no way to limit to say <supports-model> or something?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything like that at this point.  However, there is a feature request very similar to your request on the Official Android Market forum here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=6ec25d7820b978d2&hl=en

EDIT: I think I found something that was recently released that will help you out.  Check out the updated answer, or follow this link: https://market.android.com/support/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1286017

Comment: If all the clients are bought in by you what about side loading the application?

Comment: If you want the application to be private, consider a Google Play Private Channel.
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your manifest:

```
 <supports-screens 
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:xlargeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true" />
```

good luck