# How to restrict app from working on tablets?

Tags: android

I am making an android app for phones only. My UI is not optimized for tablets, so I don't want tablet users to use it. How do I restrict my app from working on tablets?

Comment: Take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636588/android-limit-supported-devices-in-android-market

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the `<compatible-screens>` element in your manifest to declare specifically what screen sizes and densities you wish to support.

The following example comes from [the documentation on this subject](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps):

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Note that the sample is flawed, as it will block your app from appearing on `-xxhdpi` devices (e.g., SONY Xperia Z, Droid DNA). You would want to add another pair of `<screen>` elements for `xxhdpi` as well to cover that scenario:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: You mean I'll have to add this line to support Xperia Z: "<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />" ? And are screenSize large and xlarge exclusively for tablets?

Comment: Adding android:xlargeScreens="false" to <supports-screens should also do the trick right?

Comment: @vergilcorleone: "And are screenSize large and xlarge exclusively for tablets?" -- there really is no such thing as a "tablet". `large` and `xlarge` cover devices that have screen sizes of 5" and above. Whether you consider those to be "tablets" is up to you. "Adding android:xlargeScreens="false" to <supports-screens should also do the trick right?" -- no, it will not.

Comment: Why won't adding android:xlargeScreens="false" to supports-screens work?

Comment: @vergilcorleone: All you are saying there is that you have not written your own support for `-xlarge` screens. Android will therefore stretch your UI for you, and your app will still ship to `-xlarge` devices.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Can you elaborate on " You would want to add another pair of <screen> elements for xxhdpi as well to cover that scenario."?

Comment: adding xxhdpi to the density prodices an error on compiling : "error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi')."

Comment: @vergilcorleone: Either update your build target to something newer (API Level 16+ should work) or simply do not support `xxhdpi` devices.

Comment: The build target is set to API level 17 already, the error is there still..

Comment: @vergilcorleone: OK, looks like there is a bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39622) that is causing the problem. Change `xxhdpi` to `480` and try that.

Comment: ok 480 works, hope it works on xxhdpi phones.